# Facebook Messenger Checkbox Plugin not displaying - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: facebook, plugins, messenger

I am trying to get this Facebook Messenger Checkbox plugin working within a landing page, but it really won't behave and I can't crack why.

It's worth noting I am using Mobile Monkey for their chatbot feature. They provided a simple script which I embedded in the head and a div that you just place where you want the checkbox to display.

Of course, it's not showing, but I'm guessing it won't work without Facebook's integration?

I have including the Facebook SDK, Messenger SDK, etc. I even got the messenger checkbox to display for a short while, but now it's decided it would rather not show itself anymore. Here's everything I have included. If I am going wrong anywhere please let me know, I don't honestly know what I'm doing with all Facebook's developer features.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '(App ID is here)',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('messenger_checkbox', function(e) {
      console.log("messenger_checkbox event");
      console.log(e);

      if (e.event == 'rendered') {
        console.log("Plugin was rendered");
      } else if (e.event == 'checkbox') {
        var checkboxState = e.state;
        console.log("Checkbox state: " + checkboxState);
      } else if (e.event == 'not_you') {
        console.log("User clicked 'not you'");
      } else if (e.event == 'hidden') {
        console.log("Plugin was hidden");
      }

    });    
};
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function confirmOptIn() {
            FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
                'app_id': '(App ID is here)',
                'page_id': '(Page ID is here)',
                'ref': '(Ref is here)',
                'user_ref': '(User Ref is here)'
            });
        }
</script>
```

Is there anything missing here? From following all of Facebook's documentation this is all I should need to get the plugin working, but I may this wrong.

Regarding mobile monkey's little html element not working, their support is terrible and really don't seem willing to offer any help into this situation.

Comment: You are correct, it's not. That's because I'm not using Customer Chat. ;)

Comment: Oops, sorry, ma bad :-) Have you gone through the list of trouble shooting tips already? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin#troubleshooting

Comment: I have, but I'm not having much luck. I'll have to come back to this at a later date. Thanks though, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the browser version of chrome? I think the fb plugin is not loaded with the chrome version 74.